# knockout: Uncaught TypeError: Object databaseViewModel.openList(this) has no method 'apply'

Tags: knockout.js

I have code like this

```
var databaseViewModel = new function () {
    var self = this;
    self.databaseList = ko.observable("");
    self.id = ko.observable("");
    self.databaseSelected = ko.observable("");
    self.description = ko.observable("description");

    self.openList = function () {
        alert("openList");
    };
}
```

html：

```
<div data-bind="foreach: databaseList">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click:'databaseViewModel.openList(this)',  attr: {   title: DataBaseName }">
                    <span class="pic1"></span><span data-bind="text:DataBaseName"></span></a></li>
                <div data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': DataBaseName }">
                    ...</div>
            </div>
```

> I want to invoke openlist when I click the link DataBaseName,how to modify the code？

Answer (score 4):

You would want to do `data-bind="click: $parent.openList"`

Check out these docs for more info on `$parent` and other special variables that you can use: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Maybe reproduce your situation in jsFiddle.  Here is one to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/shv8F/  You would want your `databaseList` to be an observableArray.